# Input field show/hide and submit issue with Javascript and html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well I've html form where 2 radio button exist. 1) Fixed 2) Tiered.

Fixed radio button has 2 field: 1) Fees 2) Additional Fees

Tiered radio button has 3 field : 1) Tier 1% 2) Tier 1$ 3) Tier 2%

So, If fixed radio  button is selected then "Fees" and "Additional Fees" field should be show.

And if Tiered radio button is selected then only "Tier 1%" and "Tier 1$" and "Tier 2%" and "Additional Fees" field should be show.

Now First issue is :  after first load the page it's showing Fees and Addition Fees field. It's ok. But if i select Tiered radio button it's show all field including "Fees". but I don't want to show this only "Fees" field.

Second Issue is : If i select Tirered it's process the page but if select Fixed then it's don't submit the page.

**Html Form**

```
<form action="agent-quote-submitted.php?property_id=<?=$property_id?>" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<tr> 
    <td>Type:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="F" id="offer_typef" name="offer_type" required />&nbsp;<b>Fixed</b>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="T" id="offer_typet" name="offer_type" required />&nbsp;<b>Tiered</b></td>  
    <script type="text/javascript">          
    $('#regForm').change(function() {
    if ($('#offer_typet').prop('checked')) {
        $('#show-me').show();
    } else {
        $('#show-me').hide();
    }
    });

    $('#regForm').change(function() {
    if ($('#offer_typef').prop('checked')) {
        $('#show-me2').show();
    } else {
        $('#show-me2').hide();
    }
    }); 
    </script>

</tr>
<tr>        
    <td colspan="3">
    <div id='show-me' style='display:none'> 
        <div class="form-group">    
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <tr>
            <td>%</td>
            <td><input name="trate1"  onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Tier 1 %" type="text" id="trate1" value="<?=$trate1?>" size="40" class="form-control" required ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$</td>
            <td><input name="trate1dollar" onkeypress="validate(event)"  placeholder=" Tier 1 $" type="text" id="trate2" value="<?=$trate2?>" size="40" class="form-control" required >     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%</td>
            <td><input name="trate2" onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Tier 2 %" type="text" id="trate2" value="<?=$trate2?>" size="40" class="form-control"  required></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>       
</tr>   
<tr>     
    <div id='show-me2' style='display:none'>
    <td>%</td>
    <td>    
    <input name="feestructure" placeholder=" Fees "   class="form-control" onKeyPress="validate(event)"  value="" type="text"  id="feestructure" size="40" required>
    </td>    
    <td></td>
    </div>    
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>$</td>
    <td><span  class="required inputfield2"></span><br> 
    <input name="budget" placeholder=" Additional fees " onkeypress="validate(event)" type="text" value="<?=$budget?>" id="fees" size="40"  class="form-control" required>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Submit Quote" class="btn btn-primary"></td>    
</tr>    
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: **Just a suggestion**: Why do you use `<table>`? it makes code really messing unless you're actually building a real data table!

Comment: @AdamAzad It's because my site is responsive and I need this <table>.

Comment: “Responsive layout” and “layout table” are more of a _contradiction_ than an actual _explanation_ …

Comment: @AdamAzad can i get the solution ?

Comment: @Babu from your question I understand that in both cases "Fixed & Tiered" the "Additional Fees" input muse be present, right?

Comment: @AdamAzad yes, its right .

Comment: @Babu: So, per my solution proffered, your real issue is your nested div/tr. Otherwise, did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this puzzled me for a bit and I tore apart your form bit by bit until I realized you have your fixed fees wrapped in a div that is nested around table rows. That ain't gonna work.

1. Make sure one of your radios is checked on load and you set your displays accordingly.
2. Make sure you can correctly hide-show elements (you can't partially hide row elements by wrapping them in a div. That is not allowed. You can wrap a table in a div, but not a row or cell. You can, however, simply hide/show the tr instead (which I do in the fiddle).
3. I would recommend adding just one listener (binding) and putting all the logic in there instead of two different binds.

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/C9jad/6/

```
$(function () {
  $('tr#feesFixed')[0].style.display = 'none';
  $('div#feesTiered')[0].style.display = 'none';
  toggleFees(); // Call this once on ready
  console.log($('#offer_typef').prop('checked'))
  console.log($('#offer_typet').prop('checked'))

  // Single binding here to call encapsulated logic
  $('#regForm input:radio').on('click', function(event){
    toggleFees();
  });

});

function toggleFees() {
  if( $('#offer_typef').prop('checked') ) {
      $('#feesTiered').hide();
      $('#feesFixed').show();
  } else {
      $('#feesFixed').hide();
      $('#feesTiered').show();
  }
};
```

I tore up a few pieces until I realized your real problem was the illegal nesting.

But that should help you fix it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

**#1 I will assume that you're working under [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) CSS framework because your `<input>` class is `form-control`**

**#2 I did remove all `<table>` tags because I couldn't understand anything from your HTML structure**

> First issue is : after first load the page it's showing Fees and
>   Addition Fees field. It's ok. But if i select Tiered radio button it's
>   show all field including "Fees". but I don't want to show this only
>   "Fees" field.

the solution for this is to wrap:

- `fixed` input into a its own `div`
- `tierd` inputs (3) into a another `div`
- Leaving `Additional fees` input without a `div` since it must be present in both cases
- I swapped and assigned `show-me` to `Fixed` and `show-me2` to `tierd` (to keep things organized)

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >

    Type: <input type="radio" value="F" id="offer_typef" name="offer_type" required checked />&nbsp;<b>Fixed</b>&nbsp; 
          <input type="radio" value="T" id="offer_typet" name="offer_type" required />&nbsp;<b>Tiered</b>   

    <!-- Fixed -->
    <div id='show-me'>
         % <input name="feestructure" placeholder=" Fees " class="form-control" onKeyPress="validate(event)" value="" type="text"  id="feestructure" size="40" required />
    </div>

    <!-- Tierd -->
    <div id='show-me2' style='display:none'> 
        <div class="form-group">    
             % <input name="trate1" onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Tier 1 %" type="text" id="trate1" value="<?=$trate1?>" size="40" class="form-control" required /> 

             $ <input name="trate1dollar" onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Tier 1 $" type="text" id="trate2" value="<?=$trate2?>" size="40" class="form-control" required />      

             % <input name="trate2" onkeypress="validate(event)" placeholder=" Tier 2 %" type="text" id="trate2" value="<?=$trate2?>" size="40" class="form-control" required /> 
         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Additional field -->    
    $ <span  class="required inputfield2"></span><br> 
         <input name="budget" placeholder=" Additional fees " onkeypress="validate(event)" type="text" value="<?=$budget?>" id="fees" size="40"  class="form-control" required />

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Submit Quote" class="btn btn-primary" />     

</form>
```

> Second Issue is : If i select Tirered it's process the page but if
>   select Fixed then it's don't submit the page.

this caused because all of your form inputs has the attribute `required`,  when you click `tiered` radio button the `show-me` `display` is set to `none` which makes impossible for the form to be submitted unless you remove the `required` attribute with JS help or validate the form on server-side

I did **simple required** changes on JS side

- `#offer_typef` attribute changes effect the div `#show-me`
- `#offer_typet` attribute changes effect the div `#show-me2`

JS:

```
$('#regForm').change(function() {

    if ($('#offer_typef').prop('checked')) {

       $('#show-me').show();
       $('#show-me input').attr('required');

    } else {

       $('#show-me input').removeAttr('required');
        $('#show-me').hide();

    }
    });

    $('#regForm').change(function() {
    if ($('#offer_typet').prop('checked')) {

        $('#show-me2').show();
    } else {
        $('#show-me2').hide();
    }

});
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/7GmGA/)

Remember: Making an input hidden (`display:none;`) doesn't mean that it won't be passed to server!

Comment: I saw the in jsFiddle it's working fine. But in my page it's not submitted the page when I press Fixed radio button. Do you know why ?

Comment: Well I did work on your workflow (your question code)! no your complete page code